# Why eps format ignores some of the subplot frames in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, frames, eps

I am trying to plot 14  subplots but when I saved the plot I noticed that all the outer frames of the second column has been ignored. You can see the image and my code below.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

a=np.random.rand(14,100)

x = np.arange(0,100)

plt.rcParams['figure.autolayout'] = True

fig, axs = plt.subplots(7, 2,figsize=(11,22))

axs[0, 0].plot(x, a[0,:], color='black')
axs[0, 1].plot(x, a[1,:], color='black')
axs[1, 0].plot(x, a[2,:], color='black')
axs[1, 1].plot(x, a[3,:], color='black')
axs[2, 0].plot(x, a[4,:], color='black')
axs[2, 1].plot(x, a[5,:], color='black')
axs[3, 0].plot(x, a[6,:], color='black')
axs[3, 1].plot(x, a[7,:], color='black')
axs[4, 0].plot(x, a[8,:], color='black')
axs[4, 1].plot(x, a[9,:], color='black')
axs[5, 1].plot(x, a[10,:], color='black')
axs[5, 0].plot(x, a[11,:], color='black')
axs[6, 0].plot(x, a[12,:], color='black')
axs[6, 1].plot(x, a[13,:], color='black')



for ax in axs.flat:
    ax.set(xlabel='Time (s)', ylabel= 'Load (kN)')
    
for row in axs: 
    for ax in row: 
        ax.grid(b=True, which='major', color='#666666', linestyle='-')    
       
plt.savefig("test.eps", dpi=1200)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Is it specific to eps, or does this happen to png and pdf too? I would try adding thi line to your code: `plt.savefig('test2.eps', dpi=1200, bbox_inches='tight')`

Comment: It just happened  in eps format, all other formats are fine. I tried  bbox_inches='tight'  before and it didn't work.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem locally.  Maybe try other eps viewers?

Comment: It is saved without those frames!    Other viewers shows the same thing.

Comment: One last test, if you convert the created eps into pdf or png, are the frames still missing? Once I had a problem with eps I think, and there was stuff outside the page, which is why it wasn't showing up.

Comment: I don't want to loss the quality of eps by converting to png.

Comment: then convert to PDF